# ASP.NET Core Response Caching Middleware - How to stop caching (500) error responses

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, responsecache

I implemented ASP.NET Core Response Caching in my application to cache some API requests.

I have added the ResponseCaching middleware to the IServicesCollection in ConfigureServices method like this.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
            builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyHeader()
                       .AllowAnyMethod();

            });
        });

        services.AddResponseCaching();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });
    }
```

I have used it in Configure method like like this.

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        if (!env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseResponseCaching();

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
           context.Response.GetTypedHeaders().CacheControl =
              new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.CacheControlHeaderValue()
              {
                  Public = true,
                  MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(apiConfiguration.CacheDuration),
              };

        context.Response.Headers[Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.HeaderNames.Vary] = new string[] { "Accept-Encoding" };
     
            await next();
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
```

I have also decorated my Web API action methods with ResponseCache attribute like below

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ResponseCache(Duration = 60)]
    public IActionResult Get(){
      //code
    }
```

Finally in my angular application I have setted Cache-control headers too.

```
  fetchAPIData(){
    return this.http.get('https://localhost:44325/data',  {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Cache-Control': 'public',
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      })
    });
  }
```

I want to cache server responses only with 200 (OK) status code. According to the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/middleware?view=aspnetcore-3.1) that should work

> Response Caching Middleware only caches server responses that result
> in a 200 (OK) status code. Any other responses, including error pages,
> are ignored by the middleware.

But when it runs it's caching 500 error responses too. look at below image
[image]

1. What can be the reason for this?
2. What should I do for fixing this. I just want to cache 200(OK) requests.

**Note**

- I tried with Chrome, Edge and IE browsers too.
- I used ASP.NET Core 3.1
- My Frontend application is Angular 7

Comment: Try adding        
 [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)] 
for Error action method in the respective controller.

Comment: Hi @Thilina Sandunsiri, I could not reproduce your issue. What about move `app.UseResponseCaching();` before `app.UseEndpoints`?

Comment: @Lakshitha This is a Web API action method for a GET request. So same method returns the Success/Error Responses
If I set "Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None", then Cache-control response header  set to "no-cache", and If I set "NoStore = true" then Cache-control response header set to "no-store". So in both scenarios it will not cache any response (even it was success)

Comment: @Lakshitha And if I set "Duration = 0" then max age of Cache-control response header becomes 0. It means cache expires as soon as response get. So each request, browser will requests a new version of the API response. So every time new API call will be send to the server.
I actually want to cache successful(200) API calls and ignore Error responses like 500,400,400

Comment: @ThilinaSandunsiri. It should be set on the Error action method.(There must be a separate action for that) According to your code, all the errors will be redirected to Error action method in the respective controller.
  app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
So the no-caching should be set on the Error action method.

Comment: @Lakshitha That is applicable only for MVC isn't it? Since it returns a separate view for Errors. For Web API it is a single API endpoint neh? We call those endpoints from the front end application.(Ex : GET 'api/students' at the time client calls that endpoint it doesn't know that will return either success/error response.It just returns the data/error info with the status code
With response caching after got the response for a given API call, client browser or proxy between the client and server which running on client's end, caching data based on the response header instructions. Isn't it?

Comment: @Rena Thanks. that was fixed my issue partially. Now it's working perfectly for IE and Firefox browsers. But for Chromium based browsers like Chrome and Edge it didn't work.

Comment: @ThilinaSandunsiri did you figure this out? I've been having the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had exactly the problem described in the question.  I'm using the ResponseCache attribute on a web api endpoint which can return either success or failure.  I was getting cache headers for both success and failure of the call.

I solved this by adding custom middleware to remove the cache headers in the failure case:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    // Do not cache error conditions
    context.Response.OnStarting(() =>
    {
        if (context.Response.StatusCode >= 400)
        {
            context.Response.Headers.Remove("Cache-Control");
        }
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    });
    await next();
});
```